# Why does ZAP think there's a Buffer Overflow in this situation?

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, zap

I'm discovering ZAP and its Active Scanner. 
I've tried to perform an Active Scanning of a variant of the vulnerable BodgeIT Store. In the `basket.jsp` page, the backend code looks like this:

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BASKETCONTENTS (BasketID, ProductID, Quantity, PriceToPay) VALUES (" + basketId + ", " + productId + ", " + Integer.parseInt(quantity) + ", " + price + ")"); // add it in the basket in the DB
```

The `quantity` variable is supposed to be an integer, whom value is gotten from the client request, as a POST parameter.

ZAP discovered that, when providing a non numerical value, the backend returns an error 500 and closes the connection:

[image]

[image]

Problem is, the backend is written in Java which has bound checking mechanism, making it impossible for a developer to introduce Buffer Overflow vulnerabilities (with the language itself).

So, why does ZAP think there's a buffer overflow, just seeing this "error 500" + "connection closed"?

**Edit**: I've checked the scan rule for Buffer Overflow and found this : https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrules/BufferOverflow.java#L119

Does ZAP report Buffer Overflow each time it gets an internal server error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some vulnerabilities are difficult to detect with absolute certainty.
In this case ZAP submitted an unusually large value and the application returned an error.

As stated in the 'Other info' this is *potentially* a buffer overflow. Its up to you to determine if it is or now. You've determined that it isnt, but you also might want to get the app changed so that it doesnt return a 500 in these cases.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm just playing around with ZAP and BodgeIT so I don't plan on changing the code. I just wanted to know why ZAP does return this potential BO vulnerability, and why it wouldn't return another potential vuln.

Now, with your answer I get why ZAP reports this BO. Thanks and have a nice day :-) !

Comment: You can always change the confidence on the issue to False Positive. For future scans if your app isn't subject to BO issues you can exclude that scanner from your scan policy. You could also setup Context Alert Filters to mark it False Positive.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Moreover, it would increase the Active Scan speed by reducing the amount of attacks performed against the application :-)